Text DISABLED but leave Scrollbar NORMAL
I can't seem to find a solution to this one. If I have a textbox that I state=DISABLE, it also disables the scrollbar.
Is there a way around this?
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
#Create an instance of tkinter frame
win = Tk()
#Set the geometry of tkinter frame
win.geometry("480x550")

def text_to_textbox(*args) -> None:         # *args as bind enter sends a position      parameter!?
response = entry_box.get()              # Get the text from the Entry box
text.config(state=NORMAL)               # Enable the textbox so you can write to it
text.insert(END,f'\n{response}')        # New line then add text at the END of the text.
text.see('end')                         # Autoscroll
entry_box.delete(0, END)
text.config(state=DISABLED)                # Delete the contents of the Entry box

textFrame = ttk.Frame(win, width=480, height=150)
textFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
scrollbar = Scrollbar(textFrame)

text= Text(textFrame, width= 50, height= 20,        background="gray71",foreground="#fff",font= ('Sans Serif', 13, 'italic bold'))
#Insert the text at the begining
text.insert(INSERT, "Hello, please Write Something...")
text.pack(expand= 1, fill= BOTH)
text.config(state=DISABLED)                 # Disable textbox so you can't write directly to it.

   scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)          # Add a scrollbar to the textbox down the right side 
    scrollbar.config(command=text.yview)        # The scrollbar goes up and down (Y position)

    responseFrame = ttk.Frame(win, width=750, height=50)
    responseFrame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
    entry_box = Entry(responseFrame, width=50)
    entry_box.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='w')
    entry_button = Button(responseFrame, text=' Send ', padx=5, pady=5)
    entry_button.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
    entry_button.config(command=text_to_textbox)
    win.bind('<Return>', text_to_textbox)

win.mainloop()

I've searched forums but can only find advice on DISABLE'ing of Text and Scrollbar.

The disabling of a text widget shouldn't affect the scrollbar. The code in the question has indentation issues so we can't run it.

You need to set the yscrollcommand option of the text widget:
text = Text(textFrame, width=50, height=20,
            background="gray71", foreground="#fff",
            font=('Sans Serif', 13, 'italic bold'),
            yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)  # set the yscrollcommand

